# How do I remove the "http://" from network_site_url?

Tags: multisite

I'm using `echo network_site_url();` to place the url of each site in a WordPress MultiSite installation.  This outputs `http://site.com/` How do I remove the `http://` and trailing slash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", '', $url);
```

Replaces http https and FTP in string $url

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain further how to implement that in my code?

Comment: `echo preg_replace("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", '', network_site_url());`